# React: Incorrect Modal component gets rendered called after axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-props, semantic-ui-react

I have taken a modal component from the [react-semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#variations-close-icon) and configured it to either have a confirm/alert like dialog or a traditional Modal.

I did this mostly to practice making more useful & reusable components and indirectly to practice managing and moving state for it to a store i.e. redux...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { logOutUser  } from '../../store/reducers/users/index'
import { modalStateOn, modalStateOff  } from '../../store/reducers/ui/index'


class MyModal extends Component {

 close = () => {
  const { modalStateOff } = this.props
  modalStateOff();
 }

 logOutUser = () => {
  const { logOutUser } = this.props
  logOutUser()
 }

 render() {
  const { modalActive } = this.props

   return (
    <>
      <Modal dimmer={'blurring'} centered={true} size={'mini'} open={modalActive} onClose={this.close}>
        <Modal.Header>
         <p>{this.props.message}</p>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Actions>
         {this.props.isAlertModal ?
         <Button
          color='black'
          onClick={this.close}
          content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
         />
         :
        <>
         <Button
           color='black'
           onClick={this.close}
          >
           No
          </Button>
          <Button
           positive
           icon='checkmark'
           labelPosition='right'
           content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
           onClick={() => { this.close(); this.logOutUser() }}
          />
        </>
         }
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
    </>
   )
 }
}

MyModal.propTypes = {
 message: PropTypes.string,
 affirmativeUsed: PropTypes.string
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { ui } = state
 const { modalActive } = ui

 return { modalActive }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ logOutUser, modalStateOn, modalStateOff }, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyModal)
```

This worked fantastically for a Modal I wanted to use for Logging out:

```
=======================================
home | profile | *dashboard | logout          /* You get a Modal to confirm your desire to log out */
=======================================
```

However on my profile page I have created an `ImageUploader` component which handles loading images for that page, As you might have guessed by now, I want a Modal to pop up as well when the `axios` request is successful and one for a failure to give some feedback...

```
=======================================
home | *profile | dashboard | logout          /* You get a Modal to confirm your desire to log out */
=======================================

        -------------
       | choose file |                       /* AND!!! Get a Modal to confirm with a success OR failure!!
        -------------
```

This is the `ImageUploader` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ImageUploader.css';
import FooModal from '../Modal/MyModal' 
import axios from 'axios';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { loadAvatar } from '../../store/reducers/users/index'
import { modalStateOn, modalStateOff } from '../../store/reducers/ui/index'

class ImageUploader extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.uploadImage = this.uploadImage.bind(this);
 }

 componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
  if (previousProps.userAvatar !== this.props.userAvatar) {
  console.log("this.props.userAvatar in componentDidUpdate", this.props.userAvatar);
   loadAvatarImage(this.props.userAvatar)
  }
 }

 setDefaultImage(){
  var defaultImage =  '../../static/profile-avatars/assets/default-img.jpg';
  this.loadAvatarImage(defaultImage)
 }

 loadAvatarImage(img) {
  var { loadAvatar } = this.props;
  loadAvatar(img)
 }

 uploadImage(e, method) {

  const { modalStateOn } = this.props
  console.log('this.props in ImageUploader uploadImageFunction', this.props)

  if (method === "multer") {

   let imageFormObj = new FormData();

   imageFormObj.append("imageName", "multer-image-" + Date.now());
   imageFormObj.append("imageData", e.target.files[0]);

   this.loadAvatarImage(window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))

   var config = { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
   axios.post(`http://localhost:8016/images/uploadmulter`, imageFormObj, config )
    .then((data) => {
     if (data.data.success) {
      console.log("data ", data);
      modalStateOn();
     return (
       <FooModal
       isAlertModal={true}
       open={true}
       affirmativeUsed="Yes"
       message="Your image has been uploaded succesfully"
      />
     )
     }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
     alert("Error while uploading image using multer");
      this.setDefaultImage();
    });
  }
    e.stopPropagation();

 }

 render() {
  var {  userAvatar } = this.props
  return (
   <>
    <div className="main-container">
     <h3 className="main-heading">Image Upload App</h3>

     <div className="image-container">
      <div className="process">
       <h4 className="process__heading">Process: Using Multer</h4>
       <p className="process__details">Upload image to a node server, connected to a MongoDB database, with the help of multer</p>
       <form action="/uploadmulter" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="avatar" className="process__upload-btn"
         onChange={(e) => {
          this.uploadImage(e, "multer");
        }} />
        <img src={userAvatar} alt="upload-image" className="process__image" />
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </>
  );
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { ui, users } = state
 const { userAvatar } = users
 const { modalActive } = ui

 return { userAvatar, modalActive }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ loadAvatar, modalStateOn }, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageUploader)
```

Interestingly enough the `Modal` for the logging out action get rendered instead of the one in the `ImageUploader`???

**AND**

When I pass in the prop value to `isAlertModal` it is ignored?!

```
  <FooModal
   isAlertModal={true}
   open={true}
   affirmativeUsed="Yes"
   message="Your image has been uploaded succesfully"
  />
```

So I suppose maybe I have to unmount the `Modal` in the nav to allow the image loader `Modal` to propagate?

*Keep in mind in the `uploadImage` function has `e.stopPropagation();` called, but no dice!

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

As Eneias suggested the rendering of this component (ImageModal) goes in the render function. Now this worked however that Modal is rendering for the logging out function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered what the problem was:

## 1. The way I was breaking up the `Modal` component was **incorrect!!!**

```
 <Modal dimmer={'blurring'} centered={true} size={'mini'} open={modalActive} onClose={this.close}>
  <Modal.Header>
   <p>{this.props.message}</p>
  </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Actions>
     {this.props.isAlertModal ?
      <Button
       color='black'
       onClick={this.close}
       content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
      />
     :
     <>
      <Button
       color='black'
       onClick={this.close}
      >
       No
      </Button>
      <Button
       positive
       icon='checkmark'
       labelPosition='right'
       content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
       onClick={() => { this.close(); this.logOutUser() }}
      />
     </>
    }
   </Modal.Actions>
 </Modal>
```

Had only one `<Model.Header>`, `this.props.message` and `<Modal.Actions>` serving two out comes in the ternary:

It should be written like this:

```
    <>
     <Modal dimmer={'blurring'} centered={true} size={'mini'} open={open} onClose={this.close}>
      {avatarModalActive === true ?
       <>
        <Modal.Header>
         <p>{this.props.message}</p>
        </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Actions>
         <Button
          color='black'
          onClick={()=> {this.close()}}
          content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
         />
         </Modal.Actions>
       </>
         :
        <>
        <Modal.Header>
         <p>{this.props.message}</p>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Actions>
         <Button
          color='black'
          onClick={this.close}
         >
           No
         </Button>
         <Button
          positive
          icon='checkmark'
          labelPosition='right'
          content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
          onClick={() => {this.close(); this.logOutUser()}}
         />
         </Modal.Actions>
        </>
         }
      </Modal>
    </>

 And I would up realizing I had one piece of `state` serving both Modals.

    const { avatarModalActive, modalActive } = this.props /* Now there are two pieces of state managing each modal */
      var open;
    
      if (avatarModalActive) open = avatarModalActive 
      else open = modalActive 

This is the complete Modal File:

import React, { PureComponent, Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { logOutUser  } from '../../store/reducers/users/index'
import { avatarModalStateOff, modalStateOff  } from '../../store/reducers/ui/index'


class MyModal extends PureComponent {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   isAlertModal: this.props.isAlertModal
  }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  const { isAlertModal } = this.props;
  this.setState({ isAlertModal: isAlertModal})
 }

 close = () => {
  if (this.props.avatarModalActive){
   this.props.avatarModalStateOff();
  }
  this.props.modalStateOff();
 }

 logOutUser = () => {
  const { logOutUser } = this.props
  logOutUser()
 }

 render() {
  const { avatarModalActive, modalActive } = this.props
  var open;

  if (avatarModalActive) open = avatarModalActive
  else open = modalActive

   return (
    <>
     <Modal dimmer={'blurring'} centered={true} size={'mini'} open={open} onClose={this.close}>
      {avatarModalActive === true ?
       <>
        <Modal.Header>
         <p>{this.props.message}</p>
        </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Actions>
         <Button
          color='black'
          onClick={()=> {this.close()}}
          content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
         />
         </Modal.Actions>
       </>
         :
        <>
        <Modal.Header>
         <p>{this.props.message}</p>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Actions>
         <Button
          color='black'
          onClick={this.close}
         >
           No
         </Button>
         <Button
          positive
          icon='checkmark'
          labelPosition='right'
          content={this.props.affirmativeUsed}
          onClick={() => {this.close(); this.logOutUser()}}
         />
         </Modal.Actions>
        </>
         }
      </Modal>
    </>
   )
 }
}

MyModal.propTypes = {
 message: PropTypes.string,
 affirmativeUsed: PropTypes.string
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { ui } = state
 const { modalActive, avatarModalActive } = ui

 return { modalActive, avatarModalActive }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ logOutUser, avatarModalStateOff, modalStateOff }, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyModal)
```

And this is the Redux file:

```
`ui.js`

/* initial state */
export var uiStartState = { modalActive: false, avatarModalActive: false, }

/* action types */
export const actionTypes = {
    MODAL_ACTIVE: 'MODAL_ACTIVE',
    MODAL_INACTIVE: 'MODAL_INACTIVE',
    AVATAR_MODAL_ACTIVE: 'AVATAR_MODAL_ACTIVE',
    AVATAR_MODAL_INACTIVE: 'AVATAR_MODAL_INACTIVE',
}

/* reducer(s) */
export default function ui(state = uiStartState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.MODAL_ACTIVE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { modalActive: true });

        case actionTypes.MODAL_INACTIVE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { modalActive: false });

        case actionTypes.AVATAR_MODAL_ACTIVE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { avatarModalActive: true });

        case actionTypes.AVATAR_MODAL_INACTIVE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { avatarModalActive: false });

        default:
            return state
    }
};

/* actions */
export const modalStateOn = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.MODAL_ACTIVE }
}

export const modalStateOff = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.MODAL_INACTIVE }
}

export const avatarModalStateOn = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.AVATAR_MODAL_ACTIVE }
}

export const avatarModalStateOff = () => {
    return { type: actionTypes.AVATAR_MODAL_INACTIVE }
}
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

Your `FooModal` should be on render funciton instead of the callback function.

The render function is called every time your state or your props change. So, you should have a flag in your state `isUploaded`, or something like that, and use it as condition to render your `FooModal`.

On the callback function of your post method, you simply update the state. It will trigger the render function again with the new state.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! However now the `FooModal` is blocking the `Logout` Modal!

Comment: Hi Antonio, check your logOutUser.  First, you import it. Then, you redeclare it as a function. Inside the function, you declare a new variable logOutUser  and call it again.. I don't know exactly what you want to do in logOutUser. Could you provide a link to your repository, or a minimal working example on codesandbox?

Comment: Hi Eneias, Oh. Perhaps I'm implementing a pattern incorrectly in regards to `logOutUser` I can provide a link to my work here `https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder/tree/hillfinder-react-semantic-ui-modal`
Thank you for taking a look!!!

Comment: Can you see if `console.log("this.props.userAvatar in componentDidUpdate", this.props.userAvatar);` is logging on console when you click on logout? I'm not sure, but the state or some property of `ImageUploader` may be changed during logout, which triggers `componentDidUpdate` and consequently `loadAvatarImage` and the modal after that...

Comment: So should that `console.log` go in `ImageUploader`...? I'd assume so.

Comment: If it is logging this means that the method is running after logout,  which causes the modal to be rendered

Comment: Ok, so the following occurred:
I placed `console.log("this.props.userAvatar in componentDidUpdate in ImageUploader", this.props.userAvatar) in the `componentDidUpdate` method in the `ImageUploader` component. And indeed it logs out `this.props.userAvatar in componentDidUpdate in ImageUploader blob:http://localhost:8016/d3cd53fd-af4f-4439-bc1d-5b03300d489b` when I click logout.
`

Comment: So why would that have to do with the modal?

Comment: The modal renders because ImageUploader updated. Why did it update? Because some property or state changed. Since you are clicking on logout, this is changing the isLogged state. The problem is that ImageUploader shouldn't be rendered when the user is not logged in. Perhaps there is something wrong with your PrivateRoute, I'm not sure. You could add the isLoggedIn condition to render your profile component  `{isloggedIn ? <Profile user/> : '' }`. Just to test.

Comment: Thanks Eneias for your insight! I'll check it out.